# Convert integers to binary, need to remove leading zero

Tags: python, binary

I wrote a program to convert an integer to binary without using `bin()`. However, when executed, this function adds a leading zero.

```
def decimalToBinary(n):
    def helper(n):
        if n == 0:
            return '0'
        else:
            if n%2 == 1:
                binaryDigit = '1'
            else:
                binaryDigit = '0'
            return helper(n//2) + binaryDigit

    helper(n)
    print(helper(n))
```

Output:

```
>>> decimalToBinary(100)
01100100
```

How can I change this so that when `100` is input, the output is `1100100`, rather than `01100100`?

Comment: you had to use empty string in `if n == 0: return ''` and other `if` to recognize when someone execute `decimalToBinary(0)` because `0` is only value which need leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Use empty string in `if n == 0: return ""` to skip this zero.

Only `0` needs "leading zero" so you have to use extra `if` to recognize this value and return `0`

```
def decimalToBinary(n):

    def helper(n):
        if n == 0:
            return '' # <- empty string
        else:
            if n%2 == 1:
                binaryDigit = '1'
            else:
                binaryDigit = '0'
            return helper(n//2) + binaryDigit

    if n == 0:
        result = '0' # <- "leading zero" only for `n == 0`
    else:
        result = helper(n)
    print(result)

# --- test ---

for x in range(16):
    decimalToBinary(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

```
 print(str(helper(n)).lstrip("0"))
```

or

```
 print(str(helper(n))[1:])
```

unless helper(n) already returns a string, in this case remove str() in the examples.

Comment: it gives empty string for `decimalToBinary(0)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of trim function.

I believe in python you will find something similar to this:

```
 trimStart("0") // example from C#
```

This is primitive method but will work for sure :)

Comment: it will trim result of `decimalToBinary(0)` to empty string.

Answer (score -2):

Something I found somewhere, a long time ago in a galaxy far away:

```
n = 100
b = ''
while n > 0:
    b = str(n % 2) + b
    n >>= 1
print(b)    # 1100100
```